# How to plot the function f(x) = sin(1/x)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to plot the function `f(x)= \sin(1/x)` on `(0,1)`. Here is my trial

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue, domain=1:2] plot({\x}, {sin(1/(\x)) r)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, the output is so strange and I do not know why. The output is

[image]

Can anyone help me in fixing this ?! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 5):

I assume, that you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

Your code gives only part between vertical dashed lines, so your code hasn't any error, only selected domain doesn't show how the frequency of `sin(1/x)` arise with x --> 0.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->]       (-0.1, 0) -- + (5,0) node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[->]       (0,-1.1) -- + (0,2.7) node[below left] {$\sin(1/x)$};
\draw[dashed]   (1,-1) -- + (0,2) (2,-1) -- + (0,2);
\foreach \i in {0.5, 1,...,4}
{
\draw (\i,0) -- + (0,-0.1) node[below,font=\scriptsize,fill=white] {\i};
}
\draw[blue,     samples=1000, domain=0.01:0.2] plot(\x, {sin(1/\x r)});
\draw[blue,smooth,samples=50, domain=0.2:5]    plot(\x, {sin(1/\x r)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Function is drawn in two parts because in this way you can spare number of samples and with this shorten computiponal time.

**Addendum:**
In case, that you like to draw this function also for negative arguments, you need to adopt domains accordingly. I suggest to draw function in two parts: with small number of samples in domains `$|x|>0.2$` and big number of samples in domains $|x|<0.2$.

If you like to restrict function domain to (-1,1) and have bigger picture, you can scale it as it is shown in MWE below.

[image]

This function you can also draw with `pgfplots`:

[image]

In this case you don't need care about of image size. It is determined by image width. However also here is smart to draw function in two parts as in pure TikZ. With this you spare time needed to draw this function.

MWE for pictures in addendum is:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
%with tikz
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2.5]
\draw[->]       (-1.1,0) -- + (2.2,0) node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[->]       (0,-1.1) -- + (0,2.7) node[below left] {$\sin(1/x)$};
\foreach \i in  {-1, -0.5,0.5,1}
{
\draw (\i,0.1) -- + (0,-0.2) node[below,font=\scriptsize,fill=white] {\i};
}
\draw[blue,samples=50,domain=-1:-0.2,smooth] plot(\x, {sin(1/(\x) r)});
\draw[blue,samples=1000,domain=-0.2:-0.01]   plot(\x, {sin(1/(\x) r)});
\draw[blue,samples=1000,domain=0.01: 0.2]    plot(\x, {sin(1/(\x) r)});
\draw[blue,samples=50,domain= 0.2: 1,smooth] plot(\x, {sin(1/(\x) r)});
    \end{tikzpicture}

% with pgfplots
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=6cm,
 axis lines=middle,
 ticklabel style={fill=white},
 xmin=-1.2,xmax=1.2,
 ymin=-1.2,ymax=1.5,,
 xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin(1/x)$,
        ]
\addplot[blue,samples=50,domain=-1:-0.2,smooth] {sin(1/\x r)};
\addplot[blue,samples=1000,domain=-0.2:-0.02]   {sin(1/\x r)};
\addplot[blue,samples=1000,domain=0.02: 0.20]   {sin(1/\x r)};
\addplot[blue,samples=50,domain= 0.2: 1,smooth] {sin(1/\x r)};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am using `documentclass{article}`. The code works fine but the scale is  is less than the normal. Is that possible to increase the scale Mr. @Zarko ?

Comment: Besides, I wrote another code

` \begin{tikzpicture}`
`  \begin{axis}[samples = 1000]`
`   \addplot[mark = none][red, thick] { sin ( 180 / ( x / pi ) ) };`
`    \end{axis}`
`       \end{tikzpicture}  `


Is it possible in such a code to declare the x and y axes and to change the scale from -6< x< 6 to be -1< x< 1 ?

Comment: see addendum to my answer