# How do I graph $f(x)=x\cdot \sin \frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I am trying to use the following thread, but whatever changes that I make lead to either an error or just a regular line being formed instead of the graph: [How to plot the function f(x) = sin(1/x)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330715/how-to-plot-the-function-fx-sin1-x)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your statements. I just replaced the function in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330715/how-to-plot-the-function-fx-sin1-x) by your function and obtain

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=\x*sin(1/\x r);}]
\begin{axis}[
    width=6cm,
 axis lines=middle,
 ticklabel style={fill=white},
 xmin=-1.2,xmax=1.2,
 ymin=-1.2,ymax=1.5,,
 xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$x\cdot\sin(1/x)$,
        ]
\addplot[blue,samples=50,domain=-1:-0.2,smooth] {f(x)};
\addplot[blue,samples=1000,domain=-0.2:-0.02]   {f(x)};
\addplot[blue,samples=1000,domain=0.02: 0.20]   {f(x)};
\addplot[blue,samples=50,domain= 0.2: 1,smooth] {f(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. My mistake was trying to use cdot instead of *. This makes a lot of sense. Could you explain why there is the r when you define f(x)?

Comment: Additionally, how should I increase the domain without the function flattening out?

Comment: @MohammedShahid The purpose of `r` is to convert radians to degrees. The second comment I do not understand. The function is what it is. Could you explain your question in a different way?